# Limit the number of results in a for loop in reverse order

Tags: php, for-loop, limit

I created a for loop to occupy a table on my site. Originally I limited the number of results by using `if (i++ <= 10) {`.

However, I adjusted the for loop so it is reverse order (most recent item first). Here is my code:

```
for ($i=count($shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList'])-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                                            $shipmentUrl = BASE_URL . "shipment.php?ShipmentID=" . $shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList'][$i]['ShipmentID'];
```

Obviously, since it's counting down instead of up, my original limit code won't work.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if ($i-- >= (count($shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList']) - (count($shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList'])-10)) {
```

My hope was it would take the total number of entries, then subtract the same number by the number I want to display (100 - (100-10) = 10 entries.

I also tried adding a 'break' at the end, assuming that this didn't work because the "count" wasn't finished yet. However that didn't work either :/

Any suggestions? Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList']` contains?

Comment: @mc10 the $shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList'] calls to a database of shipments. We use that to echo different information for a table (delivery cost, duration, distance, etc). Each column from the db is echoed in the table. One line as an example - `echo '<td>' . number_format((float) $shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList'][$i]['ActualDistance'], 2, ".", ",") . '</td>';`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
// Set the limit to the max number of results
$LIMIT = 10;
foreach (array_reverse($shipmentInfoArray['ShipmentList']) as
        $shipmentIndex => $shipment) {
    if ($shipmentIndex >= $LIMIT) {
        break;
    }

    // Use $shipment
}
```

Comment: Maybe close, but what if there are less than 10 items in the array?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Ah, forgot about that case.

Comment: That's a great point @MarkAdelsberger, we do have quite a few instances of that. Could that be resolved with an if else @mc10?

Comment: @Tim In that case, the `foreach` should iterate through the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you're making this over-complicated, and confusing yourself as you try to reason through the resulting complexity.  There are many approaches, I don't know that one is any better than another...

You could initialize a second counter (say `j`) to 0 and increment it on each iteration, as one simple solution.